# lru_cache vs cache

Tags: python-3.x, caching, or-tools

I am working with the Google OR Tools VRP with time windows implementation. I would like to activate caching to speed things up. I have python 3.7.4, so I can use @lru_cache. Is it worth it for me to upgrade to python 3.9 and use @cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L651-L653), it just does:

```py
def cache(user_function, /):
    'Simple lightweight unbounded cache.  Sometimes called "memoize".'
    return lru_cache(maxsize=None)(user_function)
```